# Como excluir uma linha do banco de dados?

Tags: php, mysql, delete

O nome da minha tabela no banco de dados é `arquivo`. Então existe uma lista de imagens e eu quero resolver, tudo em PHP

Aqui exibi

```
<?php
include ("cabecalho-tcc.php");
include("rodape-tcc.php");
//CONEXÃO COM O BANCO DE DADOS
//passando os dados necesários do banco de dados
$banco = new mysqli("localhost","root","","atlas");
//recuperar os arquivos (tabela)
$sql = "SELECT * FROM arquivo";
// irá receber o resultado da função query
$resultado = $banco -> query ($sql);

//manibular o resultado para salvar uma nova variavel, para exibir o banco de dados
while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
    # variavel vetor, ou seja, a cada laço de repetição do while será acrescentada 
    #uma nova linha, que refere aos atributos armazenados 
    $album[] = $linha;
}

?>
<body>
    <!--EXIBIR AS IMAGENS DENTRO DE UMA TABELA-->
    <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
        <tr>
            <td scope="col">Imagem</td>
            <td scope="col">Descrição</td>
            <td scope="col">Remover Imagem</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <?php
                //pegar todas a linhas que existe no album e passa para a imagem
                foreach ($album as $imagem):
            ?>
            <td width="200" height="200">
                <img class="img-thumbnail" src="<?php echo "./upload/". $imagem['imagem']?>" >
            </td>
            <td>
                <?= $imagem['descricao']?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="remove-imagem.php" class="text-danger">Remover</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php  endforeach //fechando ?>
    </table>
</body>
```

Aqui deleta

```
<?php
include ("cabecalho-tcc.php");
include ("conexao_upload.php");
include ("rodape-tcc.php");

$id = 1;

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT imagem FROM arquivo WHERE id = '".$id."'");
$arquivo = mysql_fetch_object($sql);

$sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM imagem WHERE id = '".$id."'");

unlink("upload/".$arquivo->imagem."");
?>
```

Comment: E qual o problema? Aparece algum erro? Qual? Onde?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\tcc\remove-imagem.php on line 7

Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\tcc\remove-imagem.php on line 11

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\tcc\remove-imagem.php on line 16

Warning: unlink(upload/): Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\tcc\remove-imagem.php on line 16

Comment: Eu quero que eu exclua a imagem que o usuario clicar no remover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olhando o seu código para deletar imagens, o primeiro erro que encontro é que você tentará apagar sempre a "imagem" com id = 1 no banco, pois voce declarou: `$id = 1;`, então você deve desenvolver uma solução para passar o id da imagem para o seu algoritmo.

Agora vamos aos erros que a própria aplicação avisa:

1. `Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\tcc\remove-imagem.php on line 7` isto indica que não existe um suposto índice `['id']` em um array, mas em se código não tem um array. Deve ter havido uma confusão aqui.
2. `Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in...` Este erro acontece pelo erro de sintaxe em seu comando SQL anteriormente mostrado.

Então cheguei a conclusão de que você deve consertar primeiramente a query que "recupera" a imagem no banco, para depois executar qualquer operação com ela.

Comment: Então a minha minha variável id teria que ser um array, mas do tipo $_POST? porque o o meu banco de dados que escolher o id.

Comment: não necessariamente $_POST, só precisa que o valor do id da imagem chegue dinamicamente ao algoritmo